# how to make the copy of site collection in another web application in the same SP Farm env

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How to create a  replica of `sitecollection` on a different web application in the same `spfarm`,without `backup/restore` approach[`without using content db -ssms`] approach?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have enough space available on the server.

Open SharePoint Powershell and ensure that you are running it as admin user

First take backup of the source site collection as below:

```
Backup-SPSite https://source-sitecoll-url -Path "C:\Backup\sourcesitecollection.bak"
```

This command will take the backup of the site collection and store it inside the `bak` file on the server

After that create a new web application(skip this if already created)

Now create an empty site collection in the new web application.

After that you can restore it as below:

```
Restore-SPSite https://destination-sitecoll-url -Path "C:\Backup\sourcesitecollection.bak" -Force
```

This will restore the site collection from the backup file. Here, `Force` parameter is optional

[Restore-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx)

Comment: But i am confused, why because if  we create a replica of the existing site collection, SP will assign a GUID in the SP CONFIG db. If we try to create a copy of this site, there will be a conflict of GUID in the Config DB.

Comment: Yes but the content database would be different since its a different web application. So you dont need to worry about this issue. GUID conflict will occur only when you try to restore in the same webapp